# What sour spices are there?

Tags: spices

Are there other predominantly tangy/sour spices, similar to sumac? I'm thinking of things for dressing roasted vegetables, where you might use something like lemon juice, but a dry spice can be more convenient.

Comment: I'm confused what aspect of lemon you're trying to match. Sumac matches in that it's tangy/sour.  "Zesty" isn't too clear but it seems like maybe just about every spice is zesty if these are? And none of these are hot.

Comment: Tangy/sour. Sorry I don't know the terminology well

Comment: um ... sumac ?   (is there a reason you don't want sumac?)

Comment: I do want sumac but I also want to explore its likes

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems you are asking for a list of all sour spices, possibly shortened by "goes well with roasted vegetables". Lists questions are not accepted, and "goes well with" is also not a real criterion, it's opinion based.

Comment: @rumtscho How broad is that actually? I asked about amchur substitutes (using it for the tanginess) and it got very few answers and stayed open.

Comment: With the editing by @jefromi, it's more close to a Replacement/Substitute question than a List question. To me, it's fair game this way.

Answer (score 2):

Amchoor (mango powder), anardana (dried pomegranate), and, if you include pastes, tamarinde come to mind.

They all have a tangy/sour taste, and are used quite often in Indian curries, and cooking in other parts of (South East) Asia.

Apart from mango powder (which is rich in citric acid, I use it as a replacement for lemon when I want sour, but no additional juices), I don't have any experience using them outside the realm of curries, so you'll have to experiment your way through them ;)

Comment: I've seen tamarind available in powder form before ... but I've never used it, so can't comment on how well the sourness holds up.

Comment: Heh, didn't know it existed. I only know the blocks of pressed fruits (to soak & squeeze for making your own paste), or the pre-made paste.